# docker info: are huge (tens-of-thousands) container counts normal?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

**Question**: Is it normal, so many containers and images?
    Containers: 12298
    Images: 53

This is my `docker info` output.
I've just already removed 'unused' images by
`docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep "<none>" | awk "{print \$3}")`

And have better output:

```
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             VIRTUAL SIZE
ms3_web            latest              29be36b03920        7 hours ago         824.5 MB
ms3_nginx          latest              1ca3183075d8        14 hours ago        206.5 MB
<none>              <none>              2f77583dfd8c        3 weeks ago         686 MB
python              3.4                 285252a442bf        4 weeks ago         686 MB
postgres            latest              0ded1aedd6ed        4 weeks ago         265.9 MB
tutum/nginx         latest              30a6f176d2a9        5 months ago        206.5 MB

Containers: 12298
Images: 53
Server Version: 1.9.1
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 24657
 Dirperm1 Supported: false
Execution Driver: native-0.2
Logging Driver: json-file
Kernel Version: 3.13.0-68-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS
CPUs: 1
Total Memory: 994 MiB
```

I use docker-compose for running my containers.

Should I cear Containers and Images?

Answer (score 0):

Every time you type `docker-compose up` you are initiating some number of containers to do your task. Twelve thousand sounds like a lot, but really Docker is just a new way to run a process. It's not like a traditional virtual machine. A lot of people balk at the "sizes" of images they're seeing, but because of how Docker works, it's not using up all that space for each of the images. It's only storing the filesystem layers, which are much smaller than the images they are based off. Personally, I like to keep my containers and images trimmed, but that's a matter of preference. You are not harming your system by keeping around all of those exited containers. For anyone else, you can get a list of all those containers (including containers that have exited and are no longer running) by typing `docker ps -a` and checking out the list. There are [examples online](http://zaiste.net/2014/09/removing_docker_containers/) showing ways to trim your exited containers, such as:

```
docker ps -aq --no-trunc -f status=exited | xargs docker rm
```

You can view your exited containers with a similar command:

```
docker ps -a -f status=exited
```

Something to keep in mind is that rarely you will get a container which has the status "dead" and the above command does not remove them, because our filter specifically selects only containers with "exited" status. If you want to remove *all* stopped containers, you can use something like this:

```
docker ps -aq --no-trunc | xargs docker rm
```

Just remember that Docker is only a way to run a process and not a full-blown VM like other software. It's entirely up to you what you do with your system, but this isn't nearly as bad as it sounds. You sound like you know what you're doing, and shouldn't have trouble keeping your containers and images nice and trimmed. Good luck!

Comment: And how to make containers 'trimmed'? How to remove not used images, I'm already know:
`docker rmi -f $(docker images | grep "<none>" | awk "{print \$3}")`

Comment: I added the information you requested into my answer.

Comment: There are also tools to do "garbage collection" of old images and layers. For example https://github.com/yelp/docker-custodian